# Connecting to SQL server via TCP/IP, not NP

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net, connection-string

As I found out, my SQL server has disabled Named Pipes, but enabled TCP/IP (and it will stay this way). Now I am trying to connect from the visual studio to the database, but with no luck.
I've tried so far:

```
string connstring = "Data Source=192.168.1.1:1433 ;Initial Catalog=np-sparcsn4-custom;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Password=/*****/";

string connstring = "Data Source=192.168.1.1:1433 ; Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog=np-sparcsn4-custom;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Password=/*****/";
```

I've tried to replace the IP address with name - no luck. When I try to connect using the table adapter I can preview the data, same if I'd use i.e. grid - but in the code I simply can't open connection to it: I always have Network related or server specific error, usually its either

```
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5]
```

or

```
provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server
```

Server is set up to accept remote connection and it is accessible.

**Update:**

I've tried

```
string connstring = "Server=tcp:192.168.1.1,1433 ;Initial Catalog=np-sparcsn4-custom;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=/****/";
```

or

```
"Server=tcp:ponln4report,1433 ....
```

and I've got error:

```
provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup**strong text**
```

[image]

[image]

EDI2: I've found an older SQL server 2005 that I can connect without a problem. It is a bit of a pain because it lacks i.e. Date and Time data types, but I guess it has to do for now.

Comment: Did you make sure the SQL Server has TCP/IP enabled and accessible?

Comment: yes, they are enabled

Comment: check out what's under SQL Native Client 10.0 Configuration node: does it have tcp/ip enabled?

Comment: Sorry for closing your question if it isn't actually a duplicate. Didn't expect my vote to act like a banhammer :)

Comment: Again, they are enabled, question updated

Comment: @KrisWojcik did you check both firewall and and tcp-ip protocol enabled (both 32 and 64 bit modes)?

Comment: Firewall is off, both on local machine and server, tcp-ip is on (as you can see on screenshots). Can I force using 32 bit protocol?

Answer (score 2):

For C#, use this connection string

```
connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.1,1433;Initial Catalog=np-sparcsn4-custom;Integrated Security=false;User ID=your_username;Password=your_password"
```

If you need to modify a web.config file, add this node:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
        <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.1,1433;Initial Catalog=np-sparcsn4-custom;Integrated Security=false;User ID=your_username;Password=your_password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I've tried that. "Data source" and "Server" are interchangeable.

Comment: Adding `Integrated Security=false;` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure **port 1433** is set in **IPALL** in the `SQL Configuration Manager -> Protocols` for SQLEXPRESS 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqer4.png)

Comment: no, SQL can use any port. SqlBrowser will give you the correct one